# URL Rewrite problem

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule bharani $ index.php

in my .htaccess file .

The above small snippet throwing 500 internal Server Error ,

Comment: Probably belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^index/result_id/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?result_id=$1


RewriteRule ^index/article/([0-9]+)/?$ articles.php?article_id=$1

RewriteRule ^index/product/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?productid=$1
```

Would be the best to do

Comment: Since Ids shouldn't start with a zero, I would rather do something like `^index/result_id/([1-9][0-9]*)/?$ index.php?result_id=$1` . In your regexes there is also one closing paranthesis too much.

Comment: So there is. Was a typo. I've got [0-9]+ to simplify longer numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may not use whitespaces in your regex. Try to cut the space between "bharani" and "$".

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "bharani" and "index.php"

No luck for above changes also...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^/bharani/?$ index.php
```

The /? means that the / is optional. Just incase people don't put it in.

Comment: my present URL Somthing like
https://www.atnworld.net/fb/index.php?result_id=1996
i want to change this To
https://www.atnworld.net/fb/index/result_id/1996

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+))/?$ index.php?result_id=$2
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^index/result_id/([0-9]+))/?$ index.php?result_id=$1
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?result_id=$1

This snippet fixed my prob, but one doublt is my url is like 

atnworld.net/fb/index/product/result_id/1996  
atnworld.net/fb/index/article/result_id/1996  
atnworld.net/fb/index/books/result_id/1996  

How to make this three diff url , in rewrite

Comment: Technically we've helped with your problem. So you should post these as other questions. Seems like we are doing all the work for you.

Comment: I've added a suggestion. Should help.